# How can I now obtain numerical values of $y$ from already obtained numerical values of $\frac{dy}{dx}$?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, computational-mathematics

I have numerically solved a differential equation and obtained numerical values of $\frac{dy}{dx}$ at different points of the domain space. How can I now obtain numerical values of $y$ from these values of $\frac{dy}{dx}$?

It is not possible to obtain $y$ directly from the differential equation. Finding $\frac{dy}{dx}$ itself required computation of an elliptic integral.

I don't want a computer algorithm; I want to write it myself. Just tell me the process to do it.

Comment: Unless there's something in your question I am missing, the process is called "integration". Think back to the definition of the integral as a limit of sums. Then code that up to get an approximation to the function you want.

Comment: @EthanBolker How can I integrate when I don't have the functional form of $\frac{dy}{dx}$? I just have the values of $\frac{dy}{dx}$ at different points. I cant use Euler or Runge Kutta. Or any other similar methods.

Comment: You have the values of the derivative. If I give you a table showing how fast I was going at each second for a minute you can figure out (estimate) my net displacement during that minute. No functional forms required.

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=g(y)$$
If I well understand your problem, your data set is :
$$(g_1\:,\:y_1)\:,\:(g_2\:,\:y_2)\:,\:...\:,\:(g_i\:,\:y_i)\:,\:\:,\:...\:,\:(g_n\:,\:y_n)$$
and you want to obtain $x_1\:,\:x_2\:,\:...\:,\:x_i\:,\:...\:,\:x_n$

What you need is the numerical integration of 
$$\frac{dx}{dy}=\frac{1}{g(y)}\quad\to\quad x=\int\frac{dy}{g(y)}+\text{constant}$$
$$x_{i+1}\simeq x_i+\frac12\left(\frac{1}{g_{i+1}}+\frac{1}{g_{i}}\right)(y_{i+1}-y_{i})\quad\text{ from }\quad i=1\quad\text{ to }\quad i=n-1.$$
You have to set a first value $x_1$ because the low bound of any definite integral must be defined. If not, an arbitrary constant must be added to the integral. This first point cannot come from the data set. It has to be derived from the wording of the problem and modeling. If not, for example, set $x_1=0$ , compute all the $x_i$ and afterwards, if necessary, translate the whole in adding a convenient constant to make it consistent with the wording of the problem.

IN ADDITION:

if your data set is :
$$(g_1\:,\:x_1)\:,\:(g_2\:,\:x_2)\:,\:...\:,\:(g_i\:,\:x_i)\:,\:\:,\:...\:,\:(g_n\:,\:x_n)$$
and you want to obtain $y_1\:,\:y_2\:,\:...\:,\:y_i\:,\:...\:,\:y_n$

The principle is the same.

$$y_{i+1}\simeq y_i+\frac12\left(g_{i+1}+g_{i}\right)(x_{i+1}-x_{i})\quad\text{ from }\quad i=1\quad\text{ to }\quad i=n-1.$$
You have to set a first value $y_1$ because the low bound of any definite integral must be defined. If not, an arbitrary constant must be added to the integral. This first point cannot come from the data set. It has to be derived from the wording of the problem and modeling. If not, for example, set $y_1=0$ , compute all the $y_i$ and afterwards, if necessary, translate the whole in adding a convenient constant to make it consistent with the wording of the problem.

Comment: Actually I have the ($g_i, x_i$) values and want to obtain the $y_i$ values.

Comment: This is contradictory with your comment : <<  we have $\frac{dy}{dx} =g(y) $, i.e. a function of $y$.>> . So, in fact, what you have is a function of $x$, that is $\frac{dy}{dx} =g(x) $. Nevertheless, see the addition to my first answer.

Answer (score 1):

Hint.

If you have $f'(x_i)$ for a set of points $\{x_i|\; i=0,1,2,\cdots n\}$ and the value $f(x_0)$ you can estimate the value of the function at the same points using $f(x_i)=f(x_{i-1})+f'(x_i)(x_i-x_{i-1})$.

The approximation is good if the intervals $x_i-x_{i-1}$ are small. Possibly, interpolation methods can be used as suggested [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_integration#Quadrature_rules_based_on_interpolating_functions).

Comment: Is the above mentioned relation derived from Euler's method? Looks a bit creepy as it goes against intuition. Any derivation of that one?

Comment: Yes, essentially it is the Euler method and it seems, to me, an intuitive application of the definition of the derivative as linear approximation.

Comment: One thing I would like to mention in this context: Euler's method assumes the equation of the form $\frac{dy}{dx}=f(x)$. But in this problem, while trying to solve analytically, we have $\frac{dy}{dx}=g(y)$, i.e. a function of $y$. So is Euler method valid here?

Comment: @RossMillikan: thank you.... I edit the stupid mistake !

Answer (score 1):

You can do a centered integration with $f(x_i)=f(x_{i-1})+(x_i-x_{i-1})(f'(x_i)+f'(x_{i-1}))/2$

Comment: One thing I would like to mention in this context: Euler's method assumes the equation of the form $\frac{dy}{dx}=f(x)$. But in this problem, while trying to solve analytically, we have $\frac{dy}{dx}=g(y)$, i.e. a function of $y$. So is Euler method valid here?